# Javascript-Retrieve day or month string from array based on getDay() or getMonth() return value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript using an InEasySteps textbook and I in the chapter about Dates and Time. I copied the code from the book but there is a problem trying to retrieve the day and month string from the array. it just won't let me retrieve those strings using those statements.

```js
function init(){
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", 
                  "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var now = new Date();
    var yy = now.getFullYear();               //year
    var mm = now.getMonth();                  //month name index
    var dd = now.getDate();                   //Day of the month number
    var dy = now.getDay();                    //day name index
    //convert to month name string
    mm = month[mm];         //there is a problem with this statement
    //convert to day name string
    dy = days[dy];          //there is a problem with this statement      
    var str = dy + ", " + mm + " " + dd + ", " + yy;
    panel.innerHTML += "US Date String: " + str;
    str = dy + ", " + dd + " " + mm + ", " + yy; 
    panel.innerHTML += "<br>UK Date String: " + str;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="months.js">
        </SCRIPT>
        <NOSCRIPT>
            JavaScript not enabled!
        </NOSCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div id="panel"></div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What do you get? Nothing? Errors? Be a bit more precice...

Comment: You spelled month instead of months